# ASP page error even custom error mode "ON"

Tags: asp.net, iis

I've got custom error mode "On" in my web.config. However, the ASPX error page still shows for certain kinds of particular URL

Not OK
`https://example.com/*~1*%5ca.aspx`  <-- Return 404 - File or directory not found.

OK
`https://example.com/abc.aspx` <-- can redirect to custom page

I'm using Windows Server 2012 Azure. I disabled the `NtfsDisable8dot3NameCreation` in the registry, but still no luck. What can be the root cause?

My web config

```
  <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/error/Error403.html">
      <error statusCode="400" redirect="~/error/Error400.html" />
      <error statusCode="401" redirect="~/error/Error400.html" />
      <error statusCode="402" redirect="~/error/Error400.html" />      
      <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/error/Error403.html" />
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/error/Error404.html" />
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/error/Error500.html" />
      <error statusCode="501" redirect="~/error/Error501.html" />
      <error statusCode="502" redirect="~/error/Error502.html" />
      <error statusCode="503" redirect="~/error/Error503.html" />
      <error statusCode="504" redirect="~/error/Error504.html" />
    </customErrors>

 <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Auto" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL">
       <remove statusCode="400" subStatusCode="-1"/>
       <remove statusCode="401" subStatusCode="-1"/>
       <remove statusCode="402" subStatusCode="-1"/>
       <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1"/>
       <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1"/>       
       <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1"/>
       <remove statusCode="501" subStatusCode="-1"/>
       <remove statusCode="502" subStatusCode="-1"/>
       <remove statusCode="503" subStatusCode="-1"/>
       <remove statusCode="504" subStatusCode="-1"/>
      <!--<error statusCode="500" path="error\InternalServerError.htm"/>
      <error statusCode="404" path="error\PageNotFound.htm"/>-->

       <error statusCode="400" prefixLanguageFilePath="" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/error/Error400.html" />
       <error statusCode="401" prefixLanguageFilePath="" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/error/Error400.html" />
       <error statusCode="402" prefixLanguageFilePath="" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/error/Error400.html" />
       <error statusCode="403" prefixLanguageFilePath="" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/error/Error400.html" />      
      <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/error/Error404.html" />
      <error statusCode="500" prefixLanguageFilePath="" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/error/Error500.html" />
       <error statusCode="501" prefixLanguageFilePath="" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/error/Error501.html" />
       <error statusCode="502" prefixLanguageFilePath="" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/error/Error502.html" />
       <error statusCode="503" prefixLanguageFilePath="" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/error/Error503.html" />
     <error statusCode="504" prefixLanguageFilePath="" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/error/Error504.html" />
    </httpErrors>
```

Comment: Learn what's up https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Answer (score 0):

I think you should get 400 error more than 404 error because "*" is not a valid request.path for .NET runtime and the exception was thrown from CLR. That's why IIS custom error page would never work.

Please try to set requestPathInvalidCharacters to null or manual specify invalid characters for your runtime.

```
 <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.8" />
    <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters=""/>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly">
            <error redirect="https://www.jokiesd.com/404.aspx" statusCode="404" />
        </customErrors>
  </system.web>
```

Edit：

I can' reproduce this issue on my 2012 server.  Have you tried to replace the URL to abosolute URL?

[image]